# SQLite JDBC lib is crashing in linux with heavy load

Tags: sqlite

I am using Sqlite Db on my java web application. my application is using 11gb and 13 gb to sqlite file for retrieving data. My application is read only mode. DB has tables with big Text fields.  I tried latest sqlitejdbc 3.16.1 also.

```
Stack: [0x00007f3d505ce000,0x00007f3d506cf000],  sp=0x00007f3d506cbf08,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [sqlite-3.8.11.2-69132871-257b-4cc0-8530-cdbbf7f1c30c-libsqlitejdbc.so+0x102fd]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2861  org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.step(J)I (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f3d69b50cd8 [0x00007f3d69b50ca0+0x38]
J 8657 C2 org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3PreparedStatement.executeQuery()Ljava/sql/ResultSet; (65 bytes) @ 0x00007f3d69eaeaa8 [0x00007f3d69eae920+0x188]


Second
C  [sqlite-3.8.11.2-4d106db4-b6c1-4a4b-aa7e-b98e5124305d-libsqlitejdbc.so+0x102fd]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
J 2752  org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.step(J)I (0 bytes) @ 0x00007f95e59d9bd8 [0x00007f95e59d9ba0+0x38]
```

Comment: Are you using threads?

Comment: yes it is multithread application 30 to 50 threads will be active concurrently.

Comment: Show the code that gives each thread its database connection.

Comment: Each thread are opening and closing two connection on same file and one connection on another file.  All are readonly connection. all are querying one or two records through preparedstatement.